# How to customize default buttons of AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

The problem is, I'm having an `AlertDialog`, in which I inflate my custom layout by this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
View mView  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.exp_add, null);
mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { 
                         //some of my data and mView manipulation
                    });


mBuilder.setView(mView);
AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
```

The question is how do I customize `.setPositiveButton`, because I'm having a view with a specific background color, but mBuilder adds a button with default white background color and a pink text button.

Is there any way to customize this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    //setting custom view for our dialog
    View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, null);
    builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
    builder.setView(myview);

    //creating an alert dialog from our builder.
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    //retrieving the button view in order to handle it.
    Button neutral_button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);

    Button positive_button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);


    if (neutral_button != null) {
        neutral_button.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_background));

        neutral_button.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }
    if (positive_button != null) {
        positive_button.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_background));

        positive_button.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }
```

Comment: I think  `DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL` must be `DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE`,